# Oracle job argument datetime value

Tags: oracle, date, arguments, jobs

I have a job that should execute stored procedure. The procedure has date parameter. The hours/minutes are important. However after I set the argument value like this:

```
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(job_name =>  jobName, argument_position => 1, argument_value => deadline);
```

inside the procedure the parameter contains date only (with 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds). After some googling I figured it must be because `argument_value` expects varchar so I tried passing the value like this:

```
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(job_name =>  jobName, argument_position => 1, argument_value => TO_CHAR(deadline, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

but now it looks like the procedure doesn't run at all. What is the correct way to pass date into job without losing hours and minutes?

Comment: Do you get an error when the procedure runs? ("procedure doesn't tun at all") ?? Can you post the procedure code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should've googled a little more before asking here... Turns out there's another procedure for non-varchar arguments:

```
    dbms_scheduler.set_job_anydata_value(job_name =>  jobName, argument_position => 1, argument_value => sys.anyData.convertDate(deadline));
```

This way everytinh works fine.